# CCavenue payment gateway not working magento 1.9

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, magento-1.9, ccavenue

I am currently using magento 1.9.3 version. For payment gateway I am using CCAvenue Payment gateway. It successfully installed and now it is visible in my admin panel and front end also but when I select CCAvenue option to complete payment process it is not going on CCAvenue site to process payment.

my site URL is `http://bedsheetbazaar.com/`

demo user name and password is kumarsonu1986@gmail.com

Comment: Check magento log file for error descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

The first reason may be u have not downloaded the proper extension .Download the extension from Ccavenue site.
Secondly, check the scope of the website in which u have enabled the extension.

I faced a similar problem in one of my project. I contacted the technical of CCavenue and they have given me the updated files once I replaced the old files then it was working properly.